# How to make 2 circles rotate/spin like a wheel in Matlab

Tags: matlab, rotation

I've plotted two circles and filled them with the colormap 'jet'. However, every time I try to rotate the circles using rotate function or even the spin function of colormap to make the colour jet spin inside the circle - It changes the plot entirely - Rotating only 1 circle, filling up the screen, and rotating it at an angle.

Can someone please explain how I can rotate those 2 circles, as though they are wheels of a car?

The code is as follows: (I commented out my attempt at rotating and spin)

```
%First Circle
r1 = linspace(0,1,10); 
theta1 = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);
[rg, thg] = meshgrid(r1,theta1);
[x1,y1] = pol2cart(thg,rg);
circ1 = pcolor(x1,y1,thg);
colormap(jet);

ylim([-2 2]);
hold on

%Second Circle
r2 = linspace(0,1,10); 
theta2 = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);
[rg, thg] = meshgrid(r2,theta2);

[x2,y2] = pol2cart(thg,rg);
circ2 = pcolor(x2+2.5,y2,thg); 
%colormap(jet);

%for ang=1:360
%  rotate(circ2,[0 1 1],-1);
% drawnow;
%end


%spinmap(5,1); %Spins colorjet map

view ([0 90]);
shading interp;
axis equal;
grid off;
hold off
```

Comment: Please, read [ask], and [mcve]

Comment: show your code or we can't find what's wrong

Comment: Ok - Thank you for this tip. I will do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your plotting to:

```
for ang=1:360
    cla; hold on
    circ1 = pcolor(x1,y1,thg);
    circ2 = pcolor(x2,y2,thg);
    rotate(circ2,[0 0 1],-ang);
    rotate(circ1,[0 0 1],-ang);
    set(circ1,'XData',get(circ1,'Xdata')+2.5); %change circ1 position
    view ([0 90]);
    shading interp;
    axis equal;
    grid off;
    hold off
    drawnow;
end
```

The problem with `rotate` is that rotates the whole figure, so once one circle is rotating on place, if you apply rotate again the other one will rotate around the first one. To solve that, create both circles in the same place, rotate both, and then put one in a different position

Comment: Thank you so much. This does rotate, but around the other circle. I wanted the 2 circles to remain in their place, and just spin in their place, as a car's wheel does if you're looking at the car from the side.

Comment: @Rain I see. Both of the wheels or only 1?

Comment: Both of the wheels spinning.